# Can't surroundContents with range set.Start set.setEnd

Tags: javascript, range

I need to surround multiple words with spans, I know startIndex and endIndex for each word (I'm sure no word will be spanning in multiple tags and all the words are in the same element)
I can't even select the first word, I get "IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount" and similar error with rangy ( http://jsfiddle.net/pastrocchio/hgugQ/7/ ) what am I doing wrong?

```
var range = document.createRange();
startNode = document.getElementById("texttocheck");

range.setStart(startNode, 0);
range.setEnd(startNode, 4);

var newNode = document.createElement("span");
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pastrocchio/hgugQ/3/

Comment: Are you only trying to select the first word or all of them?  Do you have to use createRange() or can you use a different approach?

Comment: some of them: the wrong ones, it will be a spellcheck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out, I was missing startnode.firstChild

```
var range = document.createRange();
startNode = document.getElementById("texttocheck");

range.setStart(startNode.firstChild, 0);
range.setEnd(startNode.firstChild, 4);

var newNode = document.createElement("span");
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```